# "Following packages have unmet dependencies" after migration from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, migration

Migration from 16.04 to 18.04 gave this error :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libglib2.0-bin : Dépend: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) mais 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 est installé
 libglib2.0-dev : Dépend: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) mais 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 est installé
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings : Dépend: libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1) mais 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 est installé
 python3-distutils : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.6.7-1~) mais 3.5.1-3 est installé
 python3-lib2to3 : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.6.7-1~) mais 3.5.1-3 est installé
 systemd : Dépend: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) mais 237-3ubuntu10.39 est installé
 udev : Dépend: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) mais 237-3ubuntu10.39 est installé
```

after ran the command :

```
do-release-upgrade
```

and restarted.

In apt.log i have this errors :

```
apt.log:Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 68
apt.log:Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 68
apt.log:Broken systemd-sysv:amd64 Est en conflit avec on systemd-shim [ amd64 ] < 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin )
apt.log:Broken systemd:amd64 Est en conflit avec on upstart [ amd64 ] < 1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1 > ( admin )
apt.log:Broken libdouble-conversion1:amd64 Casse on libdouble-conversion1v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.0.1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader [ amd64 ] < 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken imagemagick-6-common:amd64 Casse on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (< 8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~)
apt.log:Broken gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 Est en conflit avec on unity-control-center-faces [ amd64 ] < 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng12-0-dev [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng12-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1 > ( libdevel )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng3-dev [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libsane1:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libsane [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.0.27-1~)
apt.log:Broken aptdaemon:amd64 Casse on python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [ amd64 ] < 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2 > ( python )
apt.log:Broken apparmor:amd64 Casse on webbrowser-app [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken fwupd:amd64 Casse on libdfu1 [ amd64 ] < 0.8.3-0ubuntu5 > ( admin ) (< 0.9.7-1)
apt.log:Broken gnome-software:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (>= 1.1.4)
apt.log:Broken curl:amd64 Dépend on libcurl4 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 > ( libs ) (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8)
apt.log:Broken libabw-0.1-1:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libabw-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 Dépend on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14 > ( gnome ) (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-jabber [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-salut [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-yahoo [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on mcp-account-manager-uoa [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libnspr4-0d:amd64 Dépend on libnspr4 [ amd64 ] < 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 2:4.18-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 Dépend on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken vlc-bin:amd64 Casse on vlc-nox [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 > ( video ) (< 3.0.0-1~)
apt.log:Broken libnss3-1d:amd64 Dépend on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken grilo-plugins-0.3-base:amd64 Casse on grilo-plugins-0.2-base [ amd64 ] < 0.2.17-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 Casse on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqtcore0:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64 Dépend on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken python3-xapian:amd64 Est en conflit avec on python3-xapian1.3 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.4-0ubuntu1 > ( python )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqtquick0:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 Casse on libwebkitgtk-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 2.4.11-2~)
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-software:amd64 Dépend on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91)
apt.log:Broken gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.6-1ubuntu1 > ( introspection )
apt.log:Broken kerneloops:amd64 Casse on kerneloops-daemon [ amd64 ] < 0.12+git20140509-2ubuntu1 > ( utils ) (< 0.12+git20140509-6ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5)
apt.log:Broken libubuntugestures5:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-converged:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken account-plugin-aim:amd64 Dépend on empathy [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 -> 3.25.90+really3.12.14-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/gnome ) (= 3.12.11-0ubuntu3)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-web:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqt-qmlplugin [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15)
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on gstreamer1.0-packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libvlccore8:amd64 Dépend on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 -> 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Est en conflit avec on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 > ( perl )
apt.log:Broken libubuntutoolkit5:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken packagekit-tools:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5)
apt.log:Broken libsidplay2:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libsidplay2v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.1-14ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-video-mga:amd64 Dépend on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Dépend on metacity-common [ amd64 ] < 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 -> 1:3.28.0-1ubuntu0.1 > ( universe/misc ) (= 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3)
apt.log:Broken python3-pyatspi2:amd64 Dépend on python3-pyatspi [ amd64 ] < 2.18.0+dfsg-3 -> 2.26.0+dfsg-1 > ( python ) (= 2.18.0+dfsg-3)
apt.log:Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Dépend on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6)
apt.log:Broken rhythmbox-mozilla:amd64 Dépend on rhythmbox [ amd64 ] < 3.3-1ubuntu7 -> 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.3-1ubuntu7)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libmx-1.0-2:amd64 Dépend on libmx-common [ amd64 ] < 1.4.7-1ubuntu1 -> 1.99.4-1 > ( universe/misc ) (= 1.4.7-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Dépend on xorg-input-abi-22 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken appmenu-qt5:amd64 Dépend on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 Dépend on libpulse0 [ amd64 ] < 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10 -> 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4 > ( libs ) (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10)
apt.log:Broken libnss3-1d:i386 Dépend on libnss3 [ i386 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Dépend on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libnss3-nssdb:amd64 Dépend on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-qt:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libnspr4-0d:i386 Dépend on libnspr4 [ i386 ] < 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 2:4.18-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libunity-webapps0:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-common:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.3.8-0ubuntu3)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-gmail:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.4.17+14.04.20140122-0ubuntu1)
apt.log:Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 68
apt.log:Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 68
apt.log:Broken systemd-sysv:amd64 Est en conflit avec on systemd-shim [ amd64 ] < 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin )
apt.log:Broken systemd:amd64 Est en conflit avec on upstart [ amd64 ] < 1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1 > ( admin )
apt.log:Broken libdouble-conversion1:amd64 Casse on libdouble-conversion1v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.0.1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader [ amd64 ] < 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken imagemagick-6-common:amd64 Casse on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (< 8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~)
apt.log:Broken gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 Est en conflit avec on unity-control-center-faces [ amd64 ] < 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng12-0-dev [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng12-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1 > ( libdevel )
apt.log:Broken libpng-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libpng3-dev [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libsane1:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libsane [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.0.27-1~)
apt.log:Broken aptdaemon:amd64 Casse on python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [ amd64 ] < 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2 > ( python )
apt.log:Broken apparmor:amd64 Casse on webbrowser-app [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken fwupd:amd64 Casse on libdfu1 [ amd64 ] < 0.8.3-0ubuntu5 > ( admin ) (< 0.9.7-1)
apt.log:Broken gnome-software:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (>= 1.1.4)
apt.log:Broken curl:amd64 Dépend on libcurl4 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 > ( libs ) (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8)
apt.log:Broken libabw-0.1-1:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libabw-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 Dépend on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14 > ( gnome ) (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-jabber [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-salut [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on account-plugin-yahoo [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken empathy:amd64 Casse on mcp-account-manager-uoa [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (< 3.12.12-3ubuntu2)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libnspr4-0d:amd64 Dépend on libnspr4 [ amd64 ] < 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 2:4.18-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 Dépend on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken vlc-bin:amd64 Casse on vlc-nox [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 > ( video ) (< 3.0.0-1~)
apt.log:Broken libnss3-1d:amd64 Dépend on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken grilo-plugins-0.3-base:amd64 Casse on grilo-plugins-0.2-base [ amd64 ] < 0.2.17-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 Casse on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqtcore0:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64 Dépend on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken python3-xapian:amd64 Est en conflit avec on python3-xapian1.3 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.4-0ubuntu1 > ( python )
apt.log:Broken liboxideqtquick0:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 Casse on libwebkitgtk-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 2.4.11-2~)
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-software:amd64 Dépend on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91)
apt.log:Broken gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0:amd64 Est en conflit avec on gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.6-1ubuntu1 > ( introspection )
apt.log:Broken kerneloops:amd64 Casse on kerneloops-daemon [ amd64 ] < 0.12+git20140509-2ubuntu1 > ( utils ) (< 0.12+git20140509-6ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5)
apt.log:Broken libubuntugestures5:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-converged:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken account-plugin-aim:amd64 Dépend on empathy [ amd64 ] < 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 -> 3.25.90+really3.12.14-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/gnome ) (= 3.12.11-0ubuntu3)
apt.log:Broken qml-module-ubuntu-web:amd64 Dépend on liboxideqt-qmlplugin [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15)
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on gstreamer1.0-packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken libvlccore8:amd64 Dépend on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 -> 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Dépend on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Est en conflit avec on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 > ( perl )
apt.log:Broken libubuntutoolkit5:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken packagekit-tools:amd64 Dépend on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5)
apt.log:Broken libsidplay2:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libsidplay2v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.1-14ubuntu2 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-video-mga:amd64 Dépend on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Dépend on metacity-common [ amd64 ] < 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 -> 1:3.28.0-1ubuntu0.1 > ( universe/misc ) (= 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3)
apt.log:Broken python3-pyatspi2:amd64 Dépend on python3-pyatspi [ amd64 ] < 2.18.0+dfsg-3 -> 2.26.0+dfsg-1 > ( python ) (= 2.18.0+dfsg-3)
apt.log:Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Dépend on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6)
apt.log:Broken rhythmbox-mozilla:amd64 Dépend on rhythmbox [ amd64 ] < 3.3-1ubuntu7 -> 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.3-1ubuntu7)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libmx-1.0-2:amd64 Dépend on libmx-common [ amd64 ] < 1.4.7-1ubuntu1 -> 1.99.4-1 > ( universe/misc ) (= 1.4.7-1ubuntu1)
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Dépend on xorg-input-abi-22 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken appmenu-qt5:amd64 Dépend on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
apt.log:Broken pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 Dépend on libpulse0 [ amd64 ] < 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10 -> 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4 > ( libs ) (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10)
apt.log:Broken libnss3-1d:i386 Dépend on libnss3 [ i386 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Dépend on xorg-video-abi-20 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken libnss3-nssdb:amd64 Dépend on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.10)
apt.log:Broken checkbox-qt:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libnspr4-0d:i386 Dépend on libnspr4 [ i386 ] < 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 2:4.18-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
apt.log:Broken libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 Dépend on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken webapp-container:amd64 Dépend on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
apt.log:Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Dépend on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
apt.log:Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Dépend on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
apt.log:Broken libunity-webapps0:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-common:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.3.8-0ubuntu3)
apt.log:Broken unity-webapps-gmail:amd64 Dépend on unity-webapps-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.4.17+14.04.20140122-0ubuntu1)
```

During the upgrade i have a message (apt, do-release-upgrade ?) that said an error occured and to foward information to the developpers ...

How to solve this error ?

Thanks in advance for responses.

Comment: Add steps you've performed to upgrade your system.

Comment: Look in /var/log/dist-upgrade for the term.log on the date you preformed the do-releae-upgrade. Show us all the errors in that log.

Comment: Is there anyway to force apt to take the packages of the repository ?